# Бот отвечает два раза

Tags: discord

У меня бот отвечает на команды два раза. Раньше всё было нормально, но потом он начал отвечать 2 раза. Бот стоит на хостинге heroku. Раньше когда у меня было открыто два терминала то отвечал 2 раза, а сейчас только хостинг работает